# My app crashes if I change the control view repeatedly

Tags: ios, image, url, caching

I have an app that reads from a database some data ( ASIFormDataRequest ) and some images from server files ( setImageWithURL ). My app does it every time the viewController is changed (in order to have everything updated). So I guess there is an issue with cached images  If I push my app to the limit switching viewControllers repeatedly my app crashes. Why is this?

All of this has appeared after adding the setImageWithURL functions. Has anyone run into something similar?

I may have to change the way my app works  How do you guys do these calls to the server/SQL? How often?

**EDITED:(NON_ANSWERED YET ):**

XCODE does not say anything about it , when my device crashes it only displays:

> 2011-12-29 20:14:56.479 CaeDeCajon[4969:6e4f]  arrayProductos.id :13
>   id_producto: 31 2011-12-29 20:14:56.481 CaeDeCajon[4969:7b5f] 
>   arrayProductos.id :25 id_producto: 15 2011-12-29 20:14:56.490
>   CaeDeCajon[4969:7b5f]  arrayProductos.id :31 id_producto: 15
>   2011-12-29 20:14:56.491 CaeDeCajon[4969:7b5f]  arrayProductos.id :32
>   id_producto: 15 2011-12-29 20:14:56.395 CaeDeCajon[4969:955f] 
>   arrayProductos.id :22 id_producto: 35 (gdb)    // HERE IT STOPS
>   RUNNING.

for a better understanding of the question, my app is designed as follows:

- Based on a 5-icon TabBar.
- In the second icon I have a tableview with categories of products ( tables, chairs ... ) and if you press on one of them appears another viewController ( the usual detail view ) showing several products in a row ( thanks to a scrollView ) , here there is a navigationController with a button on it, when pressed it takes you to the gallery mode: showing the same products that were shown in the scrollView but in a gallery mode, if you press one of the products it takes you back to the scrollView and move your screen to the product chosen. Pretty normal stuff .
- In the third icon I have the check-out basket, where every product picked up on the scrollView (where there is a buy button  ) is pressed.

The case is that I "read" Asycn from the database all the information(no pictures) at launchingWithOptions and every time the viewController is changed, to make sure the user does not pick up a product that was sold out. I implanted this on its own and it seemed to worked fine and not to crash my app ( info : name, stock, ... only strings ). light data.

Here is where I think the problem is: I "read" all the images display from a file system in 1&1 ( hosting compony ), and seems to work fine and fast. The problem is when I swap/change the viewController repeatedly and quick between tableView-ScrollView-galleryMode , it crashed 4 times in a row for the same reason. I must say that I get the images for every viewController, for example the images in the scrollView,galleryMode and checkoutView are the same . Can I reuse them ? because I have calls to the URL everyViewController and I guess that is not healthy.

The code to download images:

> ```
> NSString *URLphotos =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.com/imagenes/%@",picture1.jpg]; // this is not always picture1.jpg but I changed it for making it plainer.
> ```
>
> [cell.photo  setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLphotos]
>   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolder.png"]] ;

Is it enough? I got no more.

wanted tips:

- How/where do you guys "read" the images from the URL in order not to crash the app but have the app updated all the time?
- Is there something going on with my cache that is making me crazy ? fix it?

Thanks in advance for the interest

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Why does your app crash? Is it out of memory or did you hit a BAD_ACCESS by trying to access a deallocated object? Without understanding the problem I don't think anyone will be able to offer a solution.

Comment: Hey Roberto can you post the code and the error you are getting? This would make it easier to help you.

Comment: When it stops, is there anything displayed in the call stack window?  (It's fairly safe to say that you have some sort of storage problem.  Since the presentation of these vary with iOS version and Xcode version you should identify which versions of those you're using.)

Comment: What does your `-(void)dealloc` methods look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are using Coredata but I had a similar experience with an app. It also had a tab bar and quickly pressing between items would cause random crashes. The issues was coredata being read / updated / deleted at the same time.

I resolved the issue by moving all of my coredata read, writes and updates to the main thread. (example in Swift):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            myDatabase("NameHere", theCommand: "TRUNCATE", theQuery: "dummy")
})
```

I made a series of functions for the common coredata commands I needed so your code will of course be different. But try running coredata on the main thread and see if your problem is solved.

If you have a CPU intensive coredata task then you will should not run on the main thread but the complexity of the solution is increased (I have only been using Xcode for 3 months) and someone else may be able to help.

But if you are using coredata try this first to see if it solves your problem.